# Nativescript use Android library

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

Could help me. I tried implement Android library in Nativescript.

I create Android Project -> New Module -> Andorid library.

Create Java Class 
**platforms\android\nativescript-serial-port\serialport\src\main\java\com\nativescript\serialport\Toaster.java**

```
 package com.nativescript.serialport;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Toaster {
    public Toaster() {}

    public void show(Context context) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hello NativeScript!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Add in file nativescript project **platforms\android\settings.gradle**

```
include ':app', ':serialport'
project(':serialport').projectDir = new File('nativescript-serial-port/serialport')
```

Add in file nativescript app **app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(":serialport")
}
```

Add in JS file nativescript project **some-file.js**

```
import * as app from 'application';

const context = android.content.Context;

const toaster = new com.nativescript.serialport.Toaster();
toaster.show(context);
```

And if I run this code appear error

> System.err: TypeError: com.nativescript.serialport.Toaster is not a constructor
>   System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js,
>   line: 372, column: 22
>       System.err:
>       System.err: StackTrace:
>       System.err:     Frame: function:'onPrint', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 372, column: 23
>       System.err:     Frame: function:'invoker', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js',
>   line: 4168, column: 18
>       System.err:     Frame: function:'Observable.notify', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js',
>   line: 17698, column: 15
>       System.err:     Frame: function:'Observable._emit', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js',
>   line: 17726, column: 12
>       System.err:     Frame: function:'ClickListenerImpl.onClick', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js',
>   line: 29193, column: 15
>       System.err:
>       System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>       System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1120)
>       System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1000)
>       System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:987)
>       System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
>       System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
>       System.err:     at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_vendor_29183_26_ClickListenerImpl.onClick(Object_vendor_29183_26_ClickListenerImpl.java:17)
>       System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
>       System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
>       System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
>       System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
>       System.err:     at android.os.Handler.h
>   andleCallback(Handler.java:873) System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) System.err:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) System.err: 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

How fix this error. Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to write a Java library when it's possible to write them in JavaScript itself. Also, you must create a standalone library project, build the aar file and copy it to your `App_Resources/android/lib`. As `platforms` folder is autogenerated one, it's not advised to make any changes in there.

Comment: Thanks. I don't build aar file. Now this is work.